# Symbol lookup failure when dynamically linking into c++ static member field

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I have the following three files:

main.hpp:

```
class A {
public:
        static int V;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.hpp"

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int A::V = 34;

int main() {
        void* handle = dlopen("./liblib.so", RTLD_NOW);
        cout << dlerror() << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

lib.cpp:

```
#include "main.hpp"

int f() {
        return A::V;
}
```

And the output of the resulting execution is:

```
$ c++ main.cpp -ldl -o main
$ c++ -shared -fpic lib.cpp -o liblib.so
$ ./main
./liblib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN1A1VE
$ nm main | grep _ZN1A1VE
0000000000601070 D _ZN1A1VE
$ nm liblib.so | grep _ZN1A1VE
                 U _ZN1A1VE
```

`nm` tells me that `_ZN1A1VE` has external linkage, hence the capital D as opposed to a lowercase one. So `liblib.so` should have no issues linking with `A::V`. But yet... Here we are. What's going on here? Can I fix this so no errors occur in linking?

Comment: If this is gcc, try this: `c++ main.cpp -rdynamic -ldl -o main` Also instead of `nm` use `nm -D`.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond `-rdynamic` worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LorinczyZsigmond pointed out, the library can't access symbols from the main executable unless you specify `-rdynamic` to the linker. So if you do this:

```
$ c++ main.cpp -rdynamic -ldl -o main
$ c++ -shared -fpic lib.cpp -o liblib.so
$ ./main
```

Everything works fine.